# Facebook PHP SDK: api('/me') strange behavior

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Since i really don't understand the $user = $facebook->getUser(); function (it returns NULL even if the user is logged in...) I'm trying with this code. The problem is, that it gives the "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user." OAuthException and if i put the login redirect code also in the Catch section it gets into a endless redirecting loop... Can someone help me?

Thank you! :)

```
try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    $scope = 'publish_stream,user_photos';

    $scope_params = explode(',',$scope);

    $permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");

if( array_key_exists('publish_stream', $permissions['data'][0]) && array_key_exists('user_photos', $permissions['data'][0])) {
  // facebook logic
 }else {
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
        <html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
        <head>
        <title>Redirect</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 

        <script language=javascript>window.open('<?php echo $loginUrl ?>', '_parent', '')</script>
        </head>
        <body>
        Redirecting...
        </body>
    </html>

        <?php
    exit;   
      }

}catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
     echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
}
```

Comment: I remember that I had a problem with facebook also trying to authenticate the user every time I wanted to redirect (that included redirect after authenticating a user). Here is a header we needed to add to fix our problem: `header ('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');`

Comment: where do i need to add this code exactly? (if i'm right this header fix is for the IE redirecting loop, i'm now on FireFox)

Comment: This is a header, so this needs to be on every page before any output starts. That should prevent it from losing authentication or variables.

Comment: nothing changes, still in redirecting loop :( redirect url is the FB Page URL, so this is the login Url : 

$params = array(
  scope => 'publish_stream,user_photos',
  redirect_uri => 'http://www.facebook.com/pages/xxxxv/123456?sk=app_123456'
 );

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

Comment: Could you please provide how your facebook object is created? :)

Comment: Are you using the latest PHP SDK?

Comment: Ohhh... there is a 3.1.1 version ?! i'm still on 3.1, so i'll try this... thanks for reminding me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution was to put all the code into one index.php file

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass active access token to the Graph API. Every access token has expiration time, and after it passes, you need to re-authenticate yourself. You should check for presence of access token in facebook's PHP SDK (`$facebook->getAccessToken();`). If it's not there - try to re-authenticate yourself. If id does not help, try using another, fresh facebook application. Whole authentication is described here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Acquiring access by hand, without using PHP SDK token is nicely described in the link above.

Comment: If i move the redirecting JS script to the catch section it still gets into endless loop... but i think this would be autenticate the app and ask for the permissions as well :(

Comment: hm... i think not, can you link some online source code, where i can check this funkction in action?

Comment: Sorry, I've accidentally removed previous comment.
In your code: try { echo $facebook->getAccessToken();exit(); } and see the output.

Comment: I tried it... it gives the token string back. (still reload loop :( )

Comment: Try connecting to API by hand, passing the access token: print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents("https: //graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=".$facebook->getAccessToken()))); (remove space after https:)

Answer (score 0):

The loop happens like this:

1. Call API
2. API says token expired / invalid
3. GetLoginUrl() -> redirect
4. Once redirected to the oauth page, it thinks that permissions and token still valid; so it redirects back to your app
5. Loop occurs (back to step 1)

Seems there is a delay between the time a token expires or a user deauthorises an app and when the oauth script actually picking up the change.

Bug Maybe?